# How many protocol types are there like http,sockets?

Tags: node.js, http, websocket, protocols, iot

I started to learn about protocols in internet communication.For beginners I start with http an build an app for my project but I am curious about other protocols like websocket which connects and make real-time connection with the server. Is there any other type.thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem.

Comment: There are thousands of protocols.  DNS for looking up a domain name.  POP3, SMTP, IMAP4 are three that are used for email.  There are dozens used for file transfers like FTP.  There are protocols for voice over IP.  Literally thousands of protocols.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of protocols out there. If you started with HTTP, you might want to stick with text based protocols at first. Try [FTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol), [POP3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol) and [SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol). After that you can check out Wikipedia for [many other protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers).